# Exportar Html con canvas a imagen

Tags: ionic4, apex

Quiero exportar un div de html y convertirlo en imagen. Lo quiero hacer en ionic, estoy teniendo dificultades por temas de incompatibilidades y demás. ¿Qué recomendáis para resolver esto?

¿Hay alguna librería o alguna forma de poder realizar esto?

Para las gráficas que tiene ese div estoy utilizando la librería apex-chart.